# Combining Wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress, themes

Is there any way to combine two Wordpress themes without using a plug-in that renders pages in different themes, and if there is, what is the most efficient way to do so? Is it as simple as copying and pasting one theme's function.php (and other files) into the first theme? Do I make a child theme?

I'm trying to build a database for clean energy initiatives across the globe, and like the map functionality of one the themes I've purchased. However, once you go pass the map, the theme is not very user-friendly and cannot hold a lot of information. This is where the second theme comes in. I want to keep both the functionalities of both themes if possible.

Comment: Hi, you could also try asking this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a way to do this, if it is just the map functionality from the first theme you want and the visual of the second one it seems like you would need to import that into the second theme.

Child themes tend to just work on css and if your first theme cannot hold a lot of information it sounds like some mark-up is missing so simply making a child theme doesn't seem like an option.

Also importing the entire functions.php file will probably clash with the existing one in certain places so that's not a good idea either.

You will basically have to extract the map from the first theme, to do this first use a program like firebug and right click on the element in your browser then inspect in firebug, this will give you an idea of what HTML elements you need in order for the map to exist, there maybe some CSS needed to so have a look at that in the inspector as well. Next you will have to look through the functions.php file to find the code you need, unfortunately there isn't really an easy way of doing this.

Could you perhaps link the themes in question or share some code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I would like to use the map from (http://themeforest.net/item/the-navigator-premium-wp-location-guide-blog/full_screen_preview/397351), with the ability to locate long/lat in the post editor, will go into the slideshow on the 1st page here: http://pixelthemes.net/?theme=immersion. I've used Headspace SEO but it only works on simple themes like the default TwentyTen.